# Getting a "cannot find proxyClass" when using vertx's WebApiServiceGen

Tags: gradle, vert.x

I'm following this example https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/web-api-service-example. Instead of using Java and Maven I'm trying to do it in Kotlin  and Gradle.  When I run the project I get a `Cannot find proxyClass:` error. My build.gradle file has this

> annotationProcessor "io.vertx:vertx-codegen:$vertxVersion:processor"
>
> annotationProcessor "io.vertx:vertx-web-api-service:$vertxVersion"
>
> compileOnly "io.vertx:vertx-codegen:$vertxVersion"
>
> compile "io.vertx:vertx-web-api-service:$vertxVersion"`

I can build successfully with Gradle

Comment: Are you using gradle 4 or gradle 5? Check out also the doc https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-api-service/java/

Comment: I'm using Gradle 5.1